# Cron job to download emails to external hard drive

Tags: email, cron, server

My client has this situation where he's constantly out ot server storage space. And he needs to archive emails from couple of years (preferably as long as possible).

He has a server (shared) with the ability to make cron jobs, the standard setup with php, apache, etc. In his office there's a external NAS Disc with mirrored RAID (static IP).

Now my first thought was to make a cron job to that would run and send all the emails older then (lest say 10 months) to the hard drive as *.eml or other format that can be opened with a installed program (like thunderbird).

After searching for a long time I could not find a solution that I thought of, and came here for pointers.

Is this possible? Or should I search for another solution?

Comment: connect by ssh, and then use "scp" command, without any coding.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this method.